# Why would I ever use StatelessWidget over StatefulWidget?

Tags: dart, flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I know that `StatefulWidget` allows us to change widgets, while `StatelessWidget` does not.

But if `StatefulWidget` can perform everything that `StatelessWidget` can perform + more, why would I ever use `StatelessWidget` over `StatefulWidget`?
Is `StatelessWidget` better in anyways other than that it's easier to implement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll get a small performance gain using `StatelessWidget`. It's very negligible but it's there.

Outside of this, there are some architectural gains. A `StatelessWidget` is *entirely* immutable. This is important enough to justify using `Stateless` over `Stateful` when there's no need for a `State`.